# Python Kivy цикл который будет выводить нужное количество блоков

Tags: python, for, kivy

Есть приложение которое должно будет в дальнейшем показывать значения из базы данных. Есть вопрос касательно цикла, мне нужно написать цикл который будет выводить нужное количество блоков, как это можно реализовать?

Скажем, я хотел бы добавить одинаковые 10 MDBoxLayout как на скрине ниже

Код закинул кусками

.py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.scrollview import MDScrollView
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.gridlayout import MDGridLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.pickers import MDDatePicker
from kivymd.uix.relativelayout import MDRelativeLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.slider import Slider
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.size = (375, 600)

class Kassa(Screen):
    pass

class ExampleApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"

ExampleApp().run()
```

.kv

```
<Kassa>:
    name: "kassa"

    MDBoxLayout:
        pos_hint: {'top': .9}
        padding: (10,15,10,0)
        md_bg_color: "#3D4051"
        orientation: 'vertical'

        ScrollView:
            do_scroll_x: False
            do_scroll_y: True
       
            MDGridLayout:
                cols: 1
                spacing: 10
                size_hint_y: None
               
                #блок который нужно прогнать в цикле так понимаю

                MDBoxLayout:
                    adaptive_height: True
                    md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
                    md_bg_color: "#434C5B"
                    radius: (10)
                    height: "75dp"

                    MDGridLayout:
                        cols: 3
                        rows: 0

                        MDLabel:
                            halign: 'center'
                            padding: 5
                            text: "Касса Такая то"

                        MDLabel:
                            halign: 'center'
                            text: "Сумма"

                        MDLabel:
                            halign: 'center'
                            text: "521"
```

Сейчас это выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]